# Thread.holdsLock() and lock coarsening

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Assume I have 2 adjacent `synchronized` blocks with a `Thread.holdsLock()` call between them:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
// ...
synchronized (lock) {
    // do stuff
}
if (Thread.holdsLock(lock)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
synchronized (lock) {
    // do more stuff
}
```

Now, what if at some point the JVM decides to [coarsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Escape_analysis_and_lock_coarsening) the lock and merge the above `synchronized` blocks? Will `Thread.holdsLock()` call still return `false`, or will the code fail with an exception?

Comment: I don't have proof, but I think coarsening can only happen if the JIT can prove that it had no visible effect. In this case it obviously would, so I'd strongly suspect the lock won't be coarsened there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good question, I would say no based on the [JSR 133 Cookbook](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html). The grid shows that a `NormalLoad` cannot be reordered above a `MonitorExit`. In this case the read would, in theory, be the lock.

Furthermore, Rafael Winterhalter mentions in a [presentation regarding the Java memory model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgiXKPEILoc) that native calls cannot be reordered, but I am having trouble finding documentation to prove this.

Comment: Please don’t rely on the cookbook, because it was designed for compiler writers. Hotspot is allowed to make further optimizations for performance purposes. I’ll try to measure it via JMH and then post what I’ve found.